# local admin overwritten by Restricted Group

Tags: active-directory

I use group policy to enforce via Restricted Group who is in the local administrators group.  However, some users we have deemed should be a local admin on their machine and they drop out of the local administrators group when the next group policy update takes place.  How can I add a user to the local administrators group and prevent it from being overwritten by the Restricted Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy is doing what it is supposed to be doing. You need an exclusion to the policy - effectively denying the policy from running on your specific computer - or an update to your methodology. My preferred method in a case like this is utilizing group policy preferences for group memberships... it's a lot more flexible.